# Meteor app crashing on startup

Tags: meteor

Inexplicably started crashing when developing this morning. Now running any meteor command returns this:

```
module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'combined-stream'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:362:17)
    at require (module.js:378:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/meteor/lib/node_modules/request/node_modules/form-data/lib/form_data.js:1:84)
    at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:362:17)
```

And the original crash log was:

```
Your app is crashing. Here's the latest log.


/usr/local/meteor/lib/node_modules/fibers/fibers.js:13
    throw new Error('`'+ modPath+ '.node` is missing. Try reinstalling `node-fibe
          ^
Error: `/usr/local/meteor/lib/node_modules/fibers/bin/darwin-x64-v8-3.11/fibers.node` is missing. Try reinstalling `node-fibers`?
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/meteor/lib/node_modules/fibers/fibers.js:13:8)
    at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:362:17)
    at require (module.js:378:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/andrei/Dropbox/CodeRookMeteor/coderookmeteor/.meteor/local/build/server/server.js:3:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
Exited with code: 1
Your application is crashing. Waiting for file change.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried restarting MongoDB, which didn't work. I also tried pulling all the code down. The issue, it seems, was with Meteor. Reinstalling it worked.

Comment: This has been happening to me too. Something in my setup forces me to reinstall Meteor every now and then while I develop. Fortunately reinstalling always fixes the problem, but I wish I knew what was causing it. It's almost like Meteor forgets where in the $PATH to look for its modules.

Comment: Thanks for this, I had the same problem too. Nothing seemed to work. Thought it was just the app, tried to create another app but the same error occurred. Wasn't quite sure why it didn't work? App was working fine last week and I hadn't made any edits since then.

Comment: My issue ended up being that I was calling a meteor-security function against a collection that I had just removed. 

    Security.permit(['insert', 'update', 'remove'])
        .collections([**GivingOptions**]).ifHasRole('admin').apply();

Once I removed this Meteor worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

After running `meteor create project_name` command change directory to project as `cd project_name` then instead of directly running `meteor`command run `meteor npm install` then run `meteor` command.

here is the snippet from official docs - [Link](https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/creating-an-app/%22Link%22) :

```
cd simple-todos
meteor npm install
meteor
```

Comment: this fixed it for me in windows