# Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'stream'

Tags: meteor, npm, reaction-commerce

Upon upgrading from Reaction Commerce v1.21.1 to v1.13.0 (which uses Meteor 1.7.0.1) I started getting the following stream error:

```Default
modules-runtime.js?hash=59942621baf2d3ff23916a0f601008fd2e310b63:241 Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'stream'
    at makeMissingError (modules-runtime.js?hash=59942621baf2d3ff23916a0f601008fd2e310b63:241)
    at require (modules-runtime.js?hash=59942621baf2d3ff23916a0f601008fd2e310b63:251)
    at bunyan.js (modules.js?hash=e8f82e706d01284fec46024b7d677bc1323d896a:47108)
    at fileEvaluate (modules-runtime.js?hash=59942621baf2d3ff23916a0f601008fd2e310b63:349)
    at require (modules-runtime.js?hash=59942621baf2d3ff23916a0f601008fd2e310b63:248)
    at main.js (modules.js?hash=e8f82e706d01284fec46024b7d677bc1323d896a:46804)
    at fileEvaluate (modules-runtime.js?hash=59942621baf2d3ff23916a0f601008fd2e310b63:349)
    at require (modules-runtime.js?hash=59942621baf2d3ff23916a0f601008fd2e310b63:248)
    at index.js (index.js:1)
    at fileEvaluate (modules-runtime.js?hash=59942621baf2d3ff23916a0f601008fd2e310b63:349)
```

I did an `rc reset -y` (equivalent to `meteor reset`) deleting all node_modules and installing anew. Alas, this attempt did not prevail.

I then found this Stack Overflow answer and tried reinstalling Meteor with the meteor install script, no to avail:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/13314141/1762493

Here's my code:

- https://github.com/MassDistributionMedia/rc-ca-blinds/tree/feature/version/rc1.13.0-dev1

Comment: did you ever resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this by using `yarn` instead of `npm install` on Meteor 1.8.0.2.

https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/10451